# How do website logins through fingerprint works?

Tags: web, fingerprint

How to website registration and login through fingerprint works?
As most of scanners dont allow you to save the image of fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

Fingerprint readers don't provide you with an image of your fingerprint. They transform the fingerprint into a **hash**. You can think of this hash as a password.

A naive implementation:
When I register, the hash of this fingerprint is saved. When I login, the same hash is sent to the app. This way, you can compare the hash at register-time and login-time, they should be the same.

In reality, fingerprint readers will often obfuscate the hash with a timebased-algorithm. The idea stays the same, though.

How this works is explained in [How does a fingerprint scanner protect its store of fingerprint data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810830/how-does-a-fingerprint-scanner-protect-its-store-of-fingerprint-data?rq=1)

---

**Edit** As ahsanic points out in his comment, not all scanners provide a hash to the application. Since there is no standard (yet), each vendor needs to define his own way of working.

It's possible that a platform manages all the user data. The user needs an account on that platform. The platform compares the hashes (invisible for the app), and when the identity is verified, the platform notifies the app that the user is logged in.

It's comparable to logging in with a Facebook account. I create a Facebook account (and not an account on your app). If I log in to your app with my Facebook account, I get redirected to Facebook and need to log in there. Facebook will  tell the application that I've logged in, and provides my personal details to the app.

A standard is in the making: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/

Comment: But for Instance, android doesnt even provide hash, it just compare the stored fingerprints. Do the laptop scanners provide hash?

Comment: Okay thanks man! I can't upvote the answer, if I would have I should have!